When using collapsible vertical el-menu (Vue.js), the content of the page grows on menu collaps, but not shrinks back on menu expand
I'm using Vue.js 3 with Element Plus.
The structure of my SPA is next:

there is an el-menu on the left
there is a router-view on the right
in that router-view, there is a header in a form of an el-row component and an el-auto-resizer that contains a table for the content


The problem I have is that when I collapse the menu, all the other content is expanded for the newly added space (which is great), however when I expand menu back, the content is not shrinking back but just pushed to the right, which makes the page to exceed the browser limits and adds a need to scroll horizontally.
I'm not sure whether it is important that I have "el-auto-resizer" there, because not only it's content remains wider, but the content of the "el-row" as well.
But on the other hand, "el-row" has "display: flex; justify-content: space-around" style, which, I assume, could make it grow along with the other content on the page and it still could be "el-auto-resizer" that causes all of this (and "el-row" just piggy-backs on it).
The structure of the main page:
<template>
  <div id="root" style="display: flex; height: 100%">
    <div style="background: rgb(73,73,73); height: 100%">
      <el-menu :router="true" :collapse="isCollapseMenu">
      ... menu items and sub-menus
      </el-menu>
    </div>
  </div>

  <router-view id="router-view" style="padding-left: 15px; padding-right: 15px; width: 100%">
</template>

The structure of the router content I have problem with:
<template>
  <div>
    <el-row style="padding-bottom: 15px; padding-top: 10px; display: flex; justify-content: space-around">
      ...some statistics elements...
    </el-row>
    <div>
      <div style="height: 70vh">
        <el-auto-resizer #default="{ height, width }">
          <el-table-v2
              :columns="columns"
              :data="data"
              :row-class="rowClass"
              :width="width"
              :height="height"
              @mouseenter.prevent=""
              @mouseleave.prevent="">
          </el-table-v2>
        </el-auto-resizer>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

I would appreciate any help on how to deal with this seemingly minor, but so annoying issue.
